# Praises about Chok L'Yisroel

Tags: minhag, torah-study

I have started learning Chok L'Yisroel and enjoying it thoroughly. I'm just wondering if there are any praises / segulas associated with it?

Comment: For those of you unfamiliar with Chok L'Yisrael, it is available in its entirety online for free (English or Hebrew) at www.echok.com . I cannot reccomend it highly enough

Comment: Check out the mifal chok inside cover - has lots of praises... from Arizal & R Chaim Vital and Others...